# How to separate words from string containing words separated by line in multi line Text Box?

Tags: c#, .net, string, cpu-word

I am  new to C# but I am interested to work with in it here is my problem:

Actually I want to take input(Keywords) from user through Multi line Text Box one key word per line and wand to store it in Database each keyword in different row.
i have tried this code:

```
Keywords objKeywords = new Keywords();
objKeywords.AddNew();
string text = txtKeywords.Text;
string[] keyword = text.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in keyword)
{
  objKeywords.SKeywords = word;
  objKeywords.ILicenseID = CommonMethods.iLicenseID;
  objKeywords.Save();
}
```

but i am getting the whole string in word(Variable). could any body please help me to correct my logic or syntax or even suggest me the new code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is `Keywords`? How is this class defined?

Comment: Keyword is my table in database and I am using that by Store Procedure through my generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will split by the space character, not new lines:

```
string[] keyword = text.Split(' ');
```

If you want to split by a new line, you should use a new line:

```
string[] keyword = text.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
string[] keyword = text.Split('\n');
```

or

```
string[] keywords= text.Split(new string[] 
{"\r\n","\r","\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Though, depending on the environment, a new line could be `\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`.